# Is there a theme for Holo, full screen but with Action Bar?

Tags: android, android-theme

I need to make an activity appear such that the activity remains full screen (no title bar) but with the Action Bar present.

App uses Holo Light for its interfaces.

Is there such a style/theme?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately, all built-in Holo Light themes with no title bar also have no action bar.  `Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar` has a title bar but no action bar, and `Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen` has neither the action bar nor the title bar.

Comment: One possible option is to try a non-Holo NoTitleBar theme and style your components with the new 4.0 look.  Not sure if this would also remove the Action Bar though.

Comment: i'm thinking of having a custom bar now :|

Comment: how its answer to this question ?

Comment: see the answer provided by @WarrenFaith which actually solves the problem!

Answer (score 65):

I had the same "issue" and what I do is basically the good old way:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

This combined with the normal `Theme.Holo` results in an UI with Actionbar but no Notification area.

Comment: why is this not marked as the answer? it solves the problem perfectly

Comment: I agree, this should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Why restriction of only ONE UP VOTE, why SO, WHY?

Answer (score 5):

Here are what you have to set to reach that:

```
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Good luck

Comment: This does not do what the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom theme that inherits Holo Light and removes the title bar.

Add the following to the res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="My.Holo.Light.FullScreen" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Than set this style as the default theme for your application in the manifest xml.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (see http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android for a full tutorial):

```
private void actionBar() {
    // remove title
    //    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#bdbb35")));
    actionBar.show();

    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);

    //TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    //  mTitleTextView.setText("My Own Title");

    actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use Theme.Holo 
it's fullscreen and with action bar
:)