# android layout with fixed top and bottombar

Tags: android

I'm trying to build an application with a fixed top and bottombar (bars should host other controls like buttons, progressbar,...).
The content (space between top/bottombar) should be able to host activities and navigates to other activies, which also could be resulting in also changing the content of both bars (also load other activities for bars).
I've started a sample with actionBar, had this issue with fullscreen mode ([Is there a theme for Holo, full screen but with Action Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134627/is-there-a-theme-for-holo-full-screen-but-with-action-bar)). Resolves my problem but setting it in code behind isn't a recommended way.

What do you think? Is there a better way to reach this kind of layout, maybe is it better to use a more simple control then actionbar?
If yes, it would be great if someone knows a starting point for layouting this (example, tut) and how to realize the navigation for the content.

I'm coming from wpf with regions, I also read posts about similar functionality on stackoverflow, but I only found examples where I missed the functionality of a dynamic content (for the bars and the content between the bars).

Tons of thanks for replies

Comment: Using frame layouts and fragments would be your best bet to achieve it. You should check that out !

Comment: @adnan thanks I've checked out [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html) . as documentation describes, flexible ui is what I need.

Comment: Yes I figured fragments would allow you the flexibility needed. :) Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

This should work (Replace middle button with say a scrollview) :

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/topbutton"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bottombutton"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/middlebutton"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottombutton"
        android:layout_below="@id/topbutton" >

    </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Reason why the bottom button has to be above the middle button in XML's order is that a view can only refer(e.g. android:layout_above) to views above itself.